# Detail field from Step Functions gets stringified in EventBridge

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions, aws-event-bridge

I have a step function `f1` which is triggered by a scheduled EventBridge Rule, so part of Execution Input is `time`.

After `f1` is completed, I want to trigger a new Step Function `f2` through a new EventBridge Rule and **pass `time` as input to `f2`**. I've tried to use [transform the input](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-transform-target-input.html) with `$.detail.input.time`, but it turns out that the `input` json gets stringified and the search expression fails

Unfortunately, I can't use `States.StringToJson` as part of the input transformation in the EventBridge rule. All I can do is to pass the horrible and stringified input (including also time as input of `f2` through `$.detail.input`).

Is there any solution to this scenario/limitation?

Answer (score 0):

Use [parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-inputpath-params.html#input-output-parameters).  StepFunction [intrinsic functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-intrinsic-functions.html)
like `States.StringToJson` are [supported](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-intrinsic-functions.html#amazon-states-language-intrinsic-functions-states) in Task & Pass parameters, but not input fields.

##### Parse incoming stringified JSON in a `Pass` State:

```json
{
  "StartAt": "ParsePass",
  "States": {
    "ParsePass": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "Parameters": {
        "payload.$": "States.StringToJson($.escapedJsonString)"
      },
      "Next": "SuccessTask"
    },
    "SuccessTask": { "Type": "Succeed" }
  }
}
```

##### Step Input

```json
{ "escapedJsonString": "{\"foo\": \"bar\"}" }
```

##### Step Output

```json
{"payload": { "foo": "bar" }}
```